# Zclip not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, flash, zclip

Hi friends I am trying to implement click to copy using zclip.

I am having different ids for same class so initially i am finding the id of the element on which i clicked and applying zclip to that element.

```
 $(".coupon_code_text").on('click', function (e) {
  pos = "#" + $(this).attr("id");
    e.preventDefault();
    clktocpy();
    function clktocpy(){

    $(pos).zclip({
            path: 'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
            copy: function () {
                return $(pos).text();
    }
});
            }
})
```

The following is the php part where I am generating different ids for the same class.

```
  <?php 
    $count = 0;
    foreach($coupons as $value)
    {
    $count = $count +1;

     <div class="coupon_code" >
          <a class="coupon_code_text" id ="copypath-<?php echo $count;?>">
                <?php echo $array['coupon_code'];?>
           </a>
     </div>


    <?php}?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that in order to get by id using jQuery you need to append a `#` to the string.

Like the following `#myId`, your variable `pos` only contains the id without the `#`.

**Line 2, fixed**

```
pos = "#" + $(this).attr("id");
```

Comment: got it but still its not wrking :/

Comment: I don't think you should be setting up zClip in every time the button is clicked, this feels like a one time thing. Look at the examples on zClip's website. http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/

Comment: actually I am implementing coupons click to copy which we ususally find in coupons site. Here i need to have click to copy for diff coupons present on that page .. so I am following this pattern

Comment: I updated it for you by loading in the zClip library, but you are still going to want to move the code that sets up zClip out form the click handlers. http://jsfiddle.net/xGk8H/3/ Updated with solution http://jsfiddle.net/xGk8H/4/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40899/discussion-between-hacker-rocker-and-hugo-tunius)